# Anyone recall a story about a perfect, wormy apple?

Tags: story-identification

I think I read it in the 90s in an SJSU creative writing class, reproduced in one of those loose leaf binders from a printshop. I may be misremembering ... but I think it was first person, a male journalist maybe? And the gist was we'd ruined the Earth by trying to make everything "better" and he was being evacuated/fleeing to space. And someone gives him an apple, and he's looking back at the Earth, and biting into it, and it's wormy, and he thinks it's PERFECT. Only the last scene with the apple stuck with me. Anyone know what this was?

Edit: John, I could be wrong, as it was a long time ago, but maybe regular food as we know it had been phased out and there was a spaceship in the short story.

Comment: Lisa, I'm sure I have read this but I cannot remember the name of the story and it's driving me mad! :-) Are there any other details you can remember about the story? Anything that might help to jog my ageing memory into life? Even apparently trivial details can help.